# Rotating an object in y axis in cocos2d iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I need to rotate an object in the y axis when the user touches the screen.
I'm new to this, and I can't find any solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should really add some code, so that we can see where you're failing. At this point we don't know if your problem is recognizing touches, rotating the object or both.

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure about what you are asking but if you mean you want to rotate some object in a 3d world there a sample in `tests` under `Effect Test` group named `FlipY3D` you can check whether it helps you are not.

Answer (score 1):

this way is rather simple. It is a BOOL statement, so that makes it easy to work with.

```
WhatYouWantToFlip.flipY = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use 
CCRotate action and can give angle in positive or negative to rotate your sprite in whichever direction you want.
CCAction *leftRotate=[CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:0.5 angle:sprite.rotation-10];
[sprite runAction:leftRotate];